# MySql - select from main table with a lot of connected tables

Tags: mysql

I have a main table, which is related to 10 other tables through one-to-many relationships.

For example:

```
main Table           table1               table2
----------           -------              -------
id *                 id*                  id*
name                 mainTableId **       mainTableId **
                     column1              column2
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM main_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 On table1.mainTableId = main_table.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 On table2.mainTableId = main_table.id
....
```

The problem is that I am getting a lot of results back, since each result in main_table is being multiplied by all the results in table1, table2, etc.

I would like to use only one SELECT query, since querying the database 10 times takes a long time.

Retrieving 100 results from each table is good enough for my needs, but trying to do the following resulted in an error that limit is not supported with a sub query:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 WHERE id in (
    SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE mainTableId = mainTable.id LIMIT 100
)
```

I am using AWS Aurora. How can I improve this query?

Comment: How many records there are in main table and slave tables (separately)? And what version of MySQL You use?

Comment: Could you provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1\G` and also for table2? You don't appear to have any join conditions which could be an issue - also why systematically a `LEFT OUTER` join?

Comment: You could probably adapt the Top-N by Group code to give what you desire:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own row-counting using user variables, as described [here](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/).

For your example it'd look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM main_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum
        FROM table_1, (SELECT @rownum := 0 FROM dual) k
        WHERE mainTableId = main_table.id
    ) 
    WHERE rownum < 100
)
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT id, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum
        FROM table_[n], (SELECT @rownum := 0 FROM dual) k
        WHERE mainTableId = main_table.id
    ) 
    WHERE rownum < 100
)
```

*[n]* would have to be replaced by the max number of tables to join.

Comment: Initiate user variable in the FROM section of subquery seems to be more safe because of the connector may not implement multi-queries. And the worst variant the connection pool with dynamic selection is used in addition.

Comment: Agreed on the first part. As for the second part: Can you please elaborate? Do you mean because it's unsafe to read AND write user variables within the same select ([as execution order is unspecified](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html))?
I've updated my answer.

Comment: *As for the second part: Can you please elaborate? Do you mean because it's unsafe to read AND write user variables within the same select* No. I mean the user variable scope is connection. If the connector not implemented multiquery, we need execute queries separately one by one in client program code. But when connection pool is used, nothing guarantee all of them will be executed in the same connection - so a lot of variables can be inaccessible for main query.

Comment: *(as execution order is unspecified)* That' right... while evaluating in one section. But sections order processing is strongly specified, so no problems in Your query can occur.

Comment: One more. You don't need to use *unique* aliases for variable-initializing subqueries - their scopes don't intersect. And You don't need to use *unique* aliases for variable names - table scan order is fixed and is performed in series because of LEFT join (and possible subquery materialization).